# HTML Hyperlink Doesn't Work in Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css

My HTML hyperlink doesn't work on the navigation bar of my webpage. I gradually transferred my `stylesheets` and `scripts` and found that after adding the `CSS file`, the hyperlink could not direct to the webpage. At first I found that the **navigation menu** was overlapped by the **slider section** (a problem mentioned in a previous *StackOverflow* problem), but I specified a high z-index for the navigation menu itself. Sorry if the code is long, but I have to give all the code to see whhat is going wrong. Please try to help make the response an actual fix, rather than just removing one of the elements to stop the overlay.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <h1><b>Seattle</b>&Metropolitan</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li>Buildings</li>
                <li id="contact">Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
<div class="image-section">
    <img src="img/seattleskyline.jpg" alt="Seattle Skyline" id="center-image" />
    <div id="caption">A panoramic view of 1201 Third Avenue at night</div>
    <button id="sliderLeft" onclick="left();"></button>
    <button id="sliderRight" onclick="right();"></button>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="content">
    Seattle's history can be traced back to the 1850s, when pioneers and natives started building a great city filled with a diverse culure, beautiful scenery, and a vibrant enviornment. The metropolitan area of Seattle now is a high-tech hub, in which four Fortune 500 companies reside: <a href="http://www.amazon.com/" alt="Amazon Website"><b>Amazon.com (#49)</b></a>, <a href="http://www.starbucks.com" alt="Starbucks Website"><b>Starbucks (#208)</b></a>, <a href="http://shop.nordstrom.com" alt="Nordstrom Website"><b>Nordstrom (#227)</b></a>, and <a href="http://www.expeditors.com" alt="Expeditors Website"><b>Expeditors International (#428)</b></a>. 
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";

body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
}

#container
{
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

header h1
{
    font-size: 38px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: 100;
}

header nav ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    float: right;
    z-index: 999;
}

header nav ul li
{
    line-height: 105px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 45px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 100;
}

header nav ul li a
{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#center-image
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 480px;
}

#contact
{
    padding-right: 0;
}

.image-section
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 75%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.image-section #caption
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background: #474747;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.image-section button
{
    outline: 0;
}

.image-section #sliderLeft
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 0;
}

.image-section #sliderRight
{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    border: 0;
}

.content
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 75%;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

.content a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.content a:visited
{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `.image-section`.

I found out by changing the `background-color:yellow;`

Apparently the links get pushed in the background.

To fix it, add `z-index:-1;` to `.image-section`.

[image]

Comment: Your answer works brilliantly. I will accept it as soon as I am able to.